# How do I get the logo specified in the azure portal branding module in password page instead of default domain logo

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have specified a logo in the branding module of Azure portal. When I redirect to password page after specifying username, the logo in the page changes to the domain which belongs to the email ID of the user.

For example, if the user email's domain is contoso.com then we get microsoft's logo in the password screen instead of the logo specified which is not my requirement. Is there a way to overwrite the default domain logo with the logo specified in the branding page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set up and save your logo in the Company Branding in the Azure portal, and click `Yes` for the `Show option to remain signed in`.

Comment: Yes i've done that but still the issues persists.

Comment: For your issue, suggest you create a support request from the Azure portal. For the details, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).